oracle apex hide page item based off a SQL query result
I would like to hide or show some page items if a sql query result is equal to 1 or 0 .
I thought I could use a DA and then use when event Page Load, but I can't seem to find away.
I have set up some flag columns in my table,
Example:
CUST_6 = 1 hide or CUST_6 = 0 show
CUST_7 = 1 hide or CUST_8 = 0 show

So if CUST_6 = 1 then hide page item 6 and then the same for CUST_7 if = 0 then show.

I also tried a Server-side Condition Rows returned with this query which will return a single value if 0 is present in the table or nothing if no 0 is present, and this didnt work.
select distinct UNIT_ID
           from CAS.AREA_TEST
          where LOCATION_ID = :P3_APEX_USER 
and UNIT_ID = :P3_CMU_3_SERIAL
and TYPE = 'CUSTOMS' 
and cust_6 = 0

Let me know if this is possible or if a different method would work for this use case.

Do you want to "Hide" the page item, or do you want to "not render/not include in the page" ? In APEX there is a fundamental difference.

"Hide" means the user does not see them but the page item is still in the DOM and can be used in page processing during page submit or shown again with dynamic actions. This can be achieved using a dynamic action.

"Not render" means that the page item is not included in the DOM at rendering time. This can be achieved using a server side condition.


From your brief description it seems that you just don't want the page items on the page at all  based on a condition that is known when the page is rendered. That means that a server-side condition (Type: "rows returned" or "no rows returned") is the way to go.
--update--
Here is an example. The functionality is that a page has 3 items: P257_ENAME, P257_SAL and P257_COMM. When P257_ENAME is entered the P257_SAL page item needs to be hidden if P257_ENAME has job PRESIDENT and the P257_COMM page item needs to be hidden if the P257_ENAME is in department SALES or ACCOUNTING.
Since there is no way to use the outcome of a select in a dynamic action condition we need to work around that by creating and populating helper page items. One page item per item that needs to be shown/hidden is needed.

Create helper page items (type hidden) P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN and P257_COMM_DISPLAY_YN

Create a dynamic action on change of P257_ENAME

True Action of type "Execute Server-side Code"
items to submit: P257_ENAME
items to return: P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN, P257_COMM_DISPLAY_YN
pl/sql code:



DECLARE
    l_dummy PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO l_dummy FROM emp WHERE ename = :P257_ENAME AND job = 'PRESIDENT';
    :P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN := 'Y';
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    :P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN := 'N';
  END;
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO l_dummy FROM emp WHERE ename = :P257_ENAME AND deptno IN (SELECT deptno FROM dept WHERE dname IN ('ACCOUNTING','SALES'));
    :P257_COMM_DISPLAY_YN := 'Y';
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    :P257_COMM_DISPLAY_YN := 'N';
  END;
END;


Add additional actions to the dynamic action to show/hide each of the page items

True Action of type "Hide"
Item P257_SAL
Client Side Condition (Item = Value) P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN, Value N
True Action of type "Show"
Item P257_SAL
Client Side Condition (Item = Value) P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN, Value Y
etc (same 2 actions for P257_COMM)



Notes

showing / hiding a page item keeps the value. So if a value of P257_SAL is set and then the page item is hidden by a dynamic action that value will still be there in the DOM. Add an additional action to clear the value when client side condition P257_SAL_DISPLAY_YN = N if you want to clear the value

Any user with a bit of html skills can play with the browser console and show a page item that was hidden by a dynamic action. Make sure there are validation on page submit to prevent unwanted data manipulation.



Thats what I thought and I tried Row returned and it still didn't work, I'll put an update to the post to include the query I used.

Please create an example based on the emp/dept sample data set. That way I can reproduce it without having your data structure and data.

I tested with emp data and it worked as expected, I think the issue is related to the fact I'm trying to use a ServerSideCond and when that runs I don't think that one of my values is populated yet so its not avalable for my where clause? :P3_CMU_3_SERIAL.  Can you think of another way to do this with Client-side and being able to query a table?

Give me a reproducible case and I'm happy to take a look. You can do that on apex.oracle.com, workspace SO_HELP, use username so_78853797, password so_78853797 - create a new app pls

How are the bind variables that are referenced in the sql query populated ? are you using "default value" ? In that case it could be that the value does not exist yet. An option is to switch to set that value using a computation before header/regions to ensure the value is set when it is referenced. Using debug on your page you can see at what point the value of an item is set.

The bind variables happen after header loads as its a user input field.  A user enter a serial number and then I lookup that serial in a ref table to get other vaules to populate on the form.  And I wanted to use a value in the ref table to tell me what items to hide on the form if needed.  But the fact the user input happens to late I don't think I can user the Server-side cond?

Correct. Not possible to add a serverside condition. A serverside condition is evaluated at page rendering time. In your case it needs to be evaluated on a browser event. That can only be done with a dynamic action. I'll put an example together.
